# AWS RDS Automated Backups

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, backup

Is it enough to just rely on the AWS automated point in time recovery/backup strategy?

Or should you also create automated periodic snapshots?

(I saw a similar question regrading this from 2012 and I know there has been AWS changes since then so wanted updated info on this)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think it is fine to rely on their backups in most use cases - that is what I do for most of my RDS instances - the one big difference to keep in mind though is if you ever delete your RDS instance, all of the automated backups get deleted with it - whereas any manual snapshots you may have taken will stick around.

That saved me one time when I deleted and instance and 3 years later needed to access some data from it - and luckily I still had a manual snapshot of the instance on my account.

Comment: Am I right in thinking with the point in time backups you can literally recover any time in your retention period? So if its set to 10, anywhere in the last 10 days? And thanks for your reply, that's really helpful.

Comment: Yes, thats my understanding - also keep in mind however restoring from a backup actually is creating a new instance for you.